# 400 invalid id token for Azure AD when ASP.net core app is deployed in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0

I have hosted my ASP.net core web app in Azure and i am using Azure AD authorisation to read roles as shown [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-1-Roles). I am getting 400 invalid id token for callback in the hosted application. In chrome console i see only this error message.I am able to see id_token in callback in network tab as well. But if i run the same code in local machine as localhost after changing redirect url to localhost i don't get any issues and I am able to read roles etc. So i believe my code is fine. What can be the reason for invalid id token error when i run the hosted application. How it can be troubleshooted.

Comment: Two possibilities 1) You have a different default browser on each machine.HTTP has a header User Agent (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) and server does not like the user agent 2) The TLS authentication version is wrong.Either you are specifying the wrong version or the version of windows you are using uses a different default than what the server uses.industry 5 years ago decided to eliminate TLS 1.0/1,1 due to security issues.  Microsoft pushed a security update in June to disable 1.0/1.1 and require 1.2/1.3 on servers. You have to modify client to work.

Comment: I have accessed the localhost application and hosted application from same browser and same machine itself. So i am not sure what is causing the issue. Minimum TLS version in the app service is set to 1.2 and i tried changing this as well, no luck. Anything else i need to check

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare good and bad sniffer results.  Check version of TLS and check the headers in the first request.  You may need to add or check a header to get code working.

Comment: @jdweng i had App Service Authentication enabled with Azure Active directory(express) settings. I disabled App service authentication in portal and now i am able to read user roles without the issue mentioned in question. So my doubt what i was doing is wrong? Do we need Authentication enabled when working with user roles?

Comment: Http in non secure and Https is the secure mode.  So when you use the non-secure mode (which you did by disabling the authentication) you do not use TLS.  When you enable authentication then you use TLS.  The TLS version when you do not set in your client software defaults to the default TLS type in Windows.   Users can set TLS version in the IE Advance Settings so different User can have different settings.  So it is best to set TLS version in your code so it always works on different machines with different users.

Comment: So when i disable App Service Authentication under the 'Authentication / Authorization' blade does it make service http instead of https. I didn't see this happening. Also there is separate option in app service to enable\disable HTTPS. Correct me if i am wrong here. Also one more doubt is if we use user roles as i mentioned in question then does OpenID internally does authentication and gets user roles?

Comment: When you make a HTTP connection there is a negotiation that occurs between client and server using the http headers to come up with a common mode (headers) of operation.  The options are changing the mode, but I'm not sure exactly which mode is being used with each option.  For example if the client request HTTP the server can come back with HTTPS is needed.  Then there are additional complications that occurs when selection the version of TLS.

Comment: The best thing to do is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  The TLS is done using TCP and comes before the HTTP Request.  So you can see in sniffer if TLS is being performed (and version) and then check the headers in the http request to see where the connection is failing.  The http response should have a status of 200 OK or an 400/500 error.

Comment: I will gives a try to use this tools to get more information.Also one more doubt is if we use user roles as i mentioned in question then does OpenID internally does authentication and gets user roles?

Comment: I looked at the source code on githup.  The code is inheriting the standard Net Library Controler.  If looks like there is a lot of options.  check the configuration file and the file 
Startup.cs for all the combinations.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue when i hosted my .net web application in Azuer App service.
go to App Service-> open your application -> goto Authentication/Authorization -> off App service Authentication.